# Remove values from dictionary based on key values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
data = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4', 'five': '5'}

keys = ('one', 'four')

unwanted = set(keys) - set(data)
for unwanted_key in unwanted: del data[unwanted_key]
```

The output that I want is:

```
data = {'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'five': '5'}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using the code of this accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys).

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/TEMn28qv)

Comment: Why are you deleting keys from `data_client_a`, not `data`?

Comment: @aIKid, is a typo. sorry

Comment: Your set subtraction is backwards, so `unwanted` is empty. The subtraction is also unneeded; see @mdml's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need this line:

```
unwanted = set(keys) - set(data)
```

Instead, just define your `unwanted` keys directly:

```
>>> data = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4', 'five': '5'}
>>> unwanted = ('one', 'four')
>>> for key in unwanted:
...     del data[key]
... 
>>> data
{'three': '3', 'five': '5', 'two': '2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation `set(keys) - set(data)` will return an empty set as it returns the difference of two sets
but what you need is the intersection of those two sets `set(keys) & set(data)`

Here's what will work for you:

```
>>> data = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3, four=4, five=5)
>>> keys = ('one', 'four')

>>> set(data)
{'four', 'one', 'five', 'three', 'two'}

>>> set(keys)
{'four', 'one'}

>>> ukeys = set(data) & set(keys)
>>> ukeys
{'four', 'one'}

>>> for uk in ukeys: del data[uk]
...
>>>

>>> data
{'five': 5, 'three': 3, 'two': 2}
```