# how to efficiently exhaust an iterator in a oneliner?

Tags: python

If i have an iterator `it` and want to exhaust it I can write:

```
for x in it:
    pass
```

Is there a builtin or standard library call which allows me to do it in a one-liner?  Of course i could do:

```
list(it)
```

which will build a list from the iterator and then discard it.  But i consider that inefficient because of the list-building step.  It's of course trivial to write myself a helper function that does the empty for loop but i am curious if there is something else i am missing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but does `[None for _ in it]` the job (or such a variant)?

Comment: Assuming you're not doing this for side effects, what's the benefit of exhausting the iterator over just discarding it?

Comment: Purely out of curiosity - why?

Comment: it's for side-effects indeed. any solution that builds up a list is more inefficient than the solution ``collections.deque(it, maxlen=0)`` below.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/50937966/8746648](Fastest (most Pythonic) way to consume an iterator)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
    # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
    collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
```

Comment: Also briefly explained here: http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-ideas/23364/

Comment: thanks -- i had tried google and stackoverflow search and not found the solution.  It should be easier to discover now :)  And ``collections.exhaust_iterator`` or ``itertools.exhaust_iterator`` would be nice and more obvious, though.

Answer (score 8):

2022 update (bounty asks): There's no "dedicated function" for it in the standard library, and `deque(it, 0)` is still the most efficient. That's why it's used in [itertools's `consume` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and [more-itertools's `consume` function](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consume) (click on [source] there).

Benchmark of the various proposals, iteration time per element, iterating `itertools.repeat(None, 10**5)` (with CPython 3.10):

```
  2.7 ns ± 0.1 ns consume_deque
  6.5 ns ± 0.0 ns consume_loop
  6.5 ns ± 0.0 ns consume_all_if_False
 13.9 ns ± 0.3 ns consume_object_in
 27.0 ns ± 0.1 ns consume_all_True
 29.4 ns ± 0.3 ns consume_sum_0
 44.8 ns ± 0.1 ns consume_reduce
```

The `deque` one wins due to being C and having a [fast path for `maxlen == 0`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/88a7f661ca02c0eb76b8f19234b8293b70f171e2/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L399-L400) which [does nothing with the elements](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/30cc1901efa18180a83bf8402df9e1c10d877c49/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L371-L372).

The simple loop gets second place, fastest with Python iteration. The other solutions previously proposed here waste more or less time by doing more or less work with each element. I added `consume_all_if_False` to show how to do an `all`/`sum` efficiently: have an `if False` clause so your generator doesn't produce anything.

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJBjtswDLz7FbytFHhTp4sAXQO59thTb0EgaG2pq1aWXEkuGgT7qH6hH0spyU5sL1AfDHDIIYdD9efwas3Tp95dr62Q0Fjjh04wbW1PVKB1AfhJ64CBMqBCBuLXc@@LYk5qxc9B3FlTWEJFl4X25btoAlPmXpwhQvOUZTnXmn1189aIkIjMldH3JCXZZ679isjmLFASUs2Kjj9W3XkYkuo/05xoh2Y2Z4w1715aDr9LONdwLjNPDqbxcIBjqpw7Xi6Q5N8Suhm3hCeD3qOTA8tMWm4JZcFlcUJ9znYQVCeiO11vXcBTSj7owCLqgPuUdrlSBeGCtdpPxU70goecbKzWqFjhlHsvXCtnoxMralSRk46bNrbPGf86SKnHlA88KB9UcyN2gpsS8Vb8KoooLhp8kTUcT@lqMl4tGf@W7hY7eCLHa4V0jgAb2InnVB9ivcfOoiWp3VGe6LHen07jecPgsOHDJQ4mwdN6v93JN8A1//6BSxKS4KcRfkBfp9eDm30T5OM@TR8XI0kcLWAlNws0qG9XbTb7FOFdDqPL5Is1ogRD8x4VJtJpSAZkfJE5tVulpq22vO@FaQnBikfsQOFDbFfcZIwuJDUl/BDnQzIvie@dMoFMZpYgt4wZjs@J0ev1Hw)):

```
def consume_loop(it):
    for _ in it:
        pass

def consume_deque(it):
    deque(it, 0)

def consume_object_in(it):
    object() in it

def consume_all_True(it):
    all(True for _ in it)

def consume_all_if_False(it):
    all(_ for _ in it if False)

def consume_sum_0(it):
    sum(0 for _ in it)

def consume_reduce(it):
    reduce(lambda x, y: y, it)

funcs = [
    consume_loop,
    consume_deque,
    consume_object_in,
    consume_all_True,
    consume_all_if_False,
    consume_sum_0,
    consume_reduce,
]

from timeit import default_timer as timer
from itertools import repeat
from collections import deque
from functools import reduce
from random import shuffle
from statistics import mean, stdev

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e9 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ns ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ns'

for _ in range(25):
  shuffle(funcs)
  for f in funcs:
    n = 10**5
    it = repeat(None, n)
    t0 = timer()
    f(it)
    t1 = timer()
    times[f].append((t1 - t0) / n)

for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
  print(stats(f), f.__name__)
```

Comment: As a supplement to "a fast path for this special case", CPython has specially written an [internal function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/30cc1901efa18180a83bf8402df9e1c10d877c49/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L365) for consuming iterator, which is [called](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L399) in `deque.extend` (and `deque.extendleft`) when `maxlen` is 0.

Comment: @MechanicPig Alright, added links after all, thanks. Was too lazy last night.

Comment: Interestingly it was added [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/060c7f6bbafdaeb4b73ce34f1bb34e4ac76f2d92). Another competitive solution is to use `itertools.islice` such as `for _ in islice(it, None, None, 1_000_000): pass`, which makes more sense to me in case they ever decide to remove the fast path for `deque`, which would honestly seem fair to me.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your suggestion can also be formulated as a one-liner:

```
for _ in it: pass
```

And I just made:

```
def exhaust(it):
    for _ in it:
        pass
```

It's not as fast as the `deque` solution (10% slower on my laptop), but I find it cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

`object() in it`

If you know the iterator will never produce a certain kind of object, you can also use that instead, e.g. `None in it` or `() in it`. The newly-created `object()` works pretty much universally, because it'll never test equal to anything else (barring shenanigans).

I'm not *advocating* this idiom; the `for` loop in the question is in many ways the best solution. But if you're looking for a creepily "elegant" answer in the sense that it does the minimum possible side-computation while still being a very neat one-liner (as opposed to e.g. `any(False for _ in it)`) then this may be it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `sum`:

```
sum(0 for _ in it)
```

or similarly, using `reduce`:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: y, it)
```

Comment: According to my benchmark, these are the two slowest, really not doing it "efficiently" (granted, I measured with newer Python, but I believe they were inefficient back then already).

Answer (score -1):

The built-in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function should be extremely cheap and simple:

```py
all(True for _ in it)
```

Edit: Fixed, thank you @hemflit !

Comment: No, this will stop iterating on first falsy element. `all(True for _ in it)` would do it though.