# dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required when updating with a tuple

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem with a dictionary that I want to split into two others.

```
dico={'GA1': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 1}, 
      'GA2': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 2}, 
      'GA3': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 3}, 
      'GA4': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 4}, 
      'GA5': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 5}, 
      'GA6': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 6}, 
      'GA7': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 7}, 
      'GA8': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 8}, 
      'GA9': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 9}, 
      'GA10': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 10}}
```

I want to put GA2 and GA6 to GA10 in a dictionary d1 and GA1 and GA3 to GA5 in a dictionary d2.

When I transform it into a list, I end up with tupples like,

```
list(dico.items())[0]
```

which gives ('GA1', {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 1})
When I want to set this into my new dictionary,

```
d2 = {}
d2.update(list(dico.items())[0])
```

I end up with "builtins.ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required"

Is a dictionary an invalid format for a tuple element ?

Thanks for your help

Alexandre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d1 = { k:dico[k] for k in ['GA2','GA6','GA10'] }
print (d1)
```

Output:

```
{'GA2': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 2}, 'GA6': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 6}, 'GA10': {'main': 1, 'middle': 1, 'sub': 10}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
d2.update([list(dico.items())[0]])
```

You can initialise a dictionary with a *list of tuples*. You were providing only a single tuple, not inside a list. Use the `[]` to initialise a singleton list and pass that:

```
{'GA10': {'middle': 1, 'main': 1, 'sub': 10}}
```

Also, doing `list(dico.items())` and then taking the 0th element is wasteful. If you can, consider changing your approach to your problem.

Comment: `d2.update([(dico.items())[0]])` - gives `TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing`

Comment: that's better now

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of the keys you want, then use a dict comprehension. Code below creates a dictionary, d2, with GA1, GA8 and GA9, key-value pairs.

```
newkeys = ['GA1', 'GA8', 'GA9']

d2 = {k: dico[k] for k in set(newkeys) & set(dico.keys())}
```

see [Filter dict to contain only certain keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys) for more info

Comment: Thank you very much