# Dictionary unpacking into function when parameters are incompatible

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not sure that it's possible, I would like to unpack dictionary into function but I haven't similar parameters. Is it possible to easily restrict a dictionary to a subset?

```
def foo(a=0, b=0, c=0):
    print("a=%s, b=%s, c=%s"%(a,b,c))

my_dict = {'a':10, 'b':20, 'd':40}
foo(**my_dict)
```

Output

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d40731664736> in <module>()
      3 
      4 my_dict = {'a':10, 'b':20, 'd':40}
----> 5 foo(**my_dict)

TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'd'
```

And I want to obtain

```
a=10, b=20, c=0
```

result where 'd' is automatically rejected.

It's just an example. In my case the function is not mine, I cannot redefined her parameters, foo is unmodifiable.

I have many functions in similar case as foo() and these functions are object's methods.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Inspecting the function signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) will help:

```
import inspect

params = inspect.signature(foo).parameters.keys()

foo(**{k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k in params})
```

Comment: Note that `inspect.signature()` is not available pre-Python 3.3. Use [`inspect.getargspec()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) in 2.x.

Comment: I thought to it and I hoped an easier solution. 
Thank you!

Comment: This solution is not correct: Try `def foo(*args): pass` and `my_dict = dict(args=0)`.

Comment: I agree that there are more complete solutions possible, depending on what scenarios need to be supported.

Comment: Well, OP says they have no control over `foo`, so that would make it a better expect anything scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (hopefully) correct solution using `inspect`. Since the parameter list returned by `inspect` may contain star args and also positional only args, it is not enough to just compare the names.

```
import inspect

def filter_kwds(f, kwds):
    params = inspect.signature(f).parameters
    if any(p.kind == inspect.Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD for p in params.values()):
        return kwds
    else:
        return {k:kwds[k] for k, v in params.items()
                if k in kwds and v.kind in (inspect.Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY,
                                            inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD)}

def f(a, *b, c=4):
    pass

def g(a, *b, c=4, **d):
    pass

print(filter_kwds(f, dict(a=1, b=2, d=4)))
print(filter_kwds(g, dict(a=1, b=2, d=4)))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Note that the function in the first example omits the name of the star arg, and in the second example detects the presence of a double star arg and therefore does no filtering