# How to format JSON to display "Class", "Score" and their values?

Tags: python, json

I'm using IBM's Watson Visual Recognition API and I'm trying to format the output JSON data to display only the "Class","Score" and both of their values

I've used

```py
print(json.dumps(classes_result, indent=2))
```

to get the output:

```
  "images": [
    {
      "classifiers": [
        {
          "classifier_id": "default",
          "name": "default",
          "classes": [
            {
              "class": "honey buzzard",
              "score": 0.639,
              "type_hierarchy": "/animal/bird/bird of prey/hawk/honey buzzard"
            },
            {
              "class": "hawk",
              "score": 0.891
            },
            {
              "class": "bird of prey",
              "score": 0.918
            },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter dict to contain only certain keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, with nested loops over your dict:

```py
for image in images:
    classifiers = image['classifiers']
    for classifier in classifiers: 
        classes = classifier['classes']
        for _class in classes: 
            class_value = _class['class']
            score_value = _class['score']
            print(class_value, score_value)
```