# Search list elements in dictionary and delete them if they don't exist

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list full of variable names and a dictionary with names and their ID's.

Example:

```
name=['name1','name2'....'name20']

dicti={'1':'name1', '2':'name2','hello':'world",'animal':'dog',...'20':'name20'}
```

What i want is to search the dictionary with elements from the list. If the list element exist in dictionary then **don't** delete it.

I got this code

```
for i in dicti.values() :
    for j in name :
        if j != i :
            del dicti[i]
        else :
            continue
```

When i run the code i got this error:

> KeyError: 'name1'

and it cannot delete the element i want.

Comment: so delete everything else apart from the ones in the list. Right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter dict to contain only certain keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `dict` comprehension

**Ex:**

```
name=set(['name1','name2','name20'])
dicti={'1':'name1', '2':'name2','hello':'world','animal':'dog',20:'name20'}
print({k:v for k, v in dicti.items() if v in name})
```

**Output:**

```
{20: 'name20', '1': 'name1', '2': 'name2'}
```

Comment: and if `name` is too big, cast to `set` first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` here.

```
name=['name1','name2'....'name20']
dicti={'1':'name1', '2':'name2','hello':'world",'animal':'dog',...'20':'name20'}
new_dict=dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] in name,dicti.items()))
print(new_dict)
```

---

output

```
{'1': 'name1', '2': 'name2',... 20: 'name20'}
```