# Python dictionary: Searching multiple keys in a dictionary to create a new one that contains them and their values

Tags: python, dictionary, search, key

I have a dictionary:

```
exampledict = {'asdf':1, 'fasdfx':2, 'basdx':3, 'gasdf':4, 'gbsdf':5}
```

and I want to be able to input and search keys that contain a text (par example "asdf"), and return a new dictionary (newdict) with these keys and their values.

```
newdict = {'asdf':1, 'fasdfx':2, 'gasdf':4}
```

Which would be the most efficient way to do it in python 3.8 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter dict to contain only certain keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys)

Answer (score 1):

Use dict comprehension:

```
exampledict = {'asdf':1, 'fasdfx':2, 'basdx':3, 'gasdf':4, 'gbsdf':5}

newdict = {k: v for k, v in exampledict.items() if 'asdf' in k}

print(newdict)
```

Prints:

```
{'asdf': 1, 'fasdfx': 2, 'gasdf': 4}
```

Comment: Thank you, for your prompt response! Sorry to ask again, but If I try to use input in search term does not seem to give the expected result. Can you point out the reason: searchterm = input('Type a searchterm: ')
exampledict = {'asdf':1, 'fasdfx':2, 'basdx':3, 'gasdf':4, 'gbsdf':5}
newdict = {k: v for k, v in exampledict.items() if 'searchterm' in k}
print(newdict)

Comment: @l34rner Try `newdict = {k: v for k, v in exampledict.items() if searchterm in k}` Without the `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dict comprehension:

```
>>> exampledict = {'asdf':1, 'fasdfx':2, 'basdx':3, 'gasdf':4, 'gbsdf':5}
>>> {k: v for k, v in exampledict.items() if 'asdf' in k}
{'asdf': 1, 'fasdfx': 2, 'gasdf': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another option like this;

```
exampledict = {'asdf':1, 'fasdfx':2, 'basdx':3, 'gasdf':4, 'gbsdf':5}

newdict = {k: exampledict[k] for k in exampledict if 'asdf' in k}
print(newdict)
```

Answer (score -2):

#your dict
exampledict = {'asdf':1, 'fasdfx':2, 'basdx':3, 'gasdf':4, 'gbsdf':5}

#the loop will traverse through the dict , k stands for key and v stands for value

for k ,v in exampledict.items():

```
if "asdf" in k:
    print(k,v)
```