# is there a method to filter dictionnary on key date?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a dictionary like :

```
  dictt =  {"2020-01-02": 34 , "2019-02-19": 43 , "2012-08-19": 52 , "2010-10-10": 10 }
```

I want to filter this dictionary based on key (date) and keeping only the date greater or equal "2012-01-01" , please help

Expected output :

```
  dictt =  {"2020-01-02": 34 , "2019-02-19": 43 , "2012-08-19": 52}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter dict to contain only certain keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dictt =  {"2020-01-02": 34 , "2019-02-19": 43 , "2012-08-19": 52 , "2010-10-10": 10 } 
dictt = {k: v for k, v in dictt.items() if k > "2012-01-01"}
print(dictt)
>> {'2020-01-02': 34, '2019-02-19': 43, '2012-08-19': 52}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the comparison with `datetime` objects:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

my_dict = {"2020-01-02": 34 , "2019-02-19": 43 , "2012-08-19": 52 , "2010-10-10": 10 }
cust_date_dict = {d: n for d, n in my_dict.items() if dt.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d') >= dt.strptime("2012-01-01", '%Y-%m-%d')}
```

Output of `print(cust_date_dict)`:

`{'2020-01-02': 34, '2019-02-19': 43, '2012-08-19': 52}`