# Create List of Dictionaries depending from a list of dictionary with key as filter

Tags: python, dictionary

I only found questions where people wanted to copy a dictionary to another depending on some keys but not for a list of dictionaries.

Lets say I have a List containing dictionaries

```
myList = [
  {'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00', 'name': 'alpha'},
  {'version': 'v5', 'updated': '2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00', 'title': 'gamma'},
  {'version': 'v7', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00', 'name': 'eta'}
]
```

now I want to create a new List of dictionaries with only keeping the keys `version` and `updated`. There is a high chance that the dictionaries also have some keys different from each other like it is shown in `myList` with `name` and `title`. But that shouldn't bother me as I know that the keys I want to filter with are the same in every dictionary. So it is important for me to use `version` and `updated` and not something like dropping everything with `name` or `title`. The result should be a new list of dictionaries

```
myFilteredList= [
  {'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-08-24 17:37:00+00:00'},
  {'version': 'v5', 'updated': '2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00'},
  {'version': 'v7', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'}
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter dict to contain only certain keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys)

Comment: Where is the date `2020-08-24` supposed to come from in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension to filter within a list comprehension for each dictionary. Basically check if the key is in your desired set, and if so, keep that pair in your newly generated dict.

```
>>> [{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in {'version', 'updated'}} for d in myList]
[{'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'},
 {'version': 'v5', 'updated': '2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00'},
 {'version': 'v7', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new list of dictionaries with those keys

```
myFilteredList = [{'version': d.get('version'), 'updated': d.get('updated')} for d in myList]

# [{'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'},
#  {'version': 'v5', 'updated': '2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00'},
#  {'version': 'v7', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'}]
```