# Split python dictionary into 2 new dic and sort by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I get a dictionary back from an API call and would like to clean up and split the dictionary into 2 new dictionaries.

ob = ( the whole dictionary from the API )
b_ob = should only have 5 first items where SIDE=BUY and only the price KEY and VAL
s_ob = should only have 5 first items where SIDE=SELL and only the price KEY and VAL

Here is the dictionary from API Call:

````
 {'price': '47296.5', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 0.002},
 {'price': '47296', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 0.002},
 {'price': '47295.5', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 0.003},
 {'price': '47295', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 0.002},
 {'price': '47294.5', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 0.002},
 {'price': '47294', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 0.002},
 {'price': '47293.5', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 0.002},
 {'price': '47293', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 0.002},
 {'price': '47297.5', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 0.016},
 {'price': '47298', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 0.01},
 {'price': '47298.5', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 0.003},
 {'price': '47299.5', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 0.002},
 {'price': '47300', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 4.39},
 {'price': '47300.5', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 4.365},
 {'price': '47301', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 9.638},
 {'price': '47301.5', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 0.623},
 {'price': '47302', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 1.107},
 {'price': '47302.5', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 2.223} ```
````

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: that's actually a list of dictionaries

Comment: It's only a List and not code or error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take "5 first items where", I'd use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) for "where" and then slice the result with either plain `list(filtered_objects)[:5]` or `list(itertools.islice(filtered_objects, 5))` for better performance on large lists.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys) should help with removing extra keys from dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your original list and apply your conditionals (BUY vs SELL and LIMIT of 5). Below is an approach using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

sides = defaultdict(list)
grouped = groupby(ob, key=itemgetter("side"))

for k, v in grouped:
    if len(sides[k]) == 5:
        continue
    for price in v:
        sides[k].append({"price": v["price"]})
```

The final output will be a dictionary where the keys will be either `Buy` or `Sell` and the values will be the dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you very much. Had difficulties but is probably due to a lack of experience with python.