# Speed dict mapping vs if elif

Tags: python

I have a function implemented as a `lambda` as well as a `if elif ...` and compared the execution time :

```
light = lambda c, v: {'turn on': 1,
                      'turn off': 0,
                      'toggle': (v+1)%2}[c]

def l(c, v):
    if c == 'turn on':
        return 1
    elif c == 'turn off':
        return 0
    elif c == 'toggle':
        return (v+1)%2
    return v

t = Timer(lambda: light('turn on', 0))
print('light: ' + str(t.timeit(number=23163958)))

t = Timer(lambda: l('turn on', 0))
print('l: ' + str(t.timeit(number=23163958)))
```

The output is:

```
light: 8.976719211001182
l: 3.9458757909887936
```

Why is the `if` statement almost twice as fast? Is it possible to increase the performance even more? I have to execute the function over 23 million times.

According to this I thought the dict lookup would be faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15925086/2014080

Comment: its not just the difference between the conditionals and dictionary lookup, its the overhead of the lambda id imagine

Comment: Putting the dict in a function def is equally slow.

Comment: Why have you decided that lambda would be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each call of the lambda you instantiate the dictionary again, this takes time. If the dictionary is just being referenced, not created, it runs quicker than the conditionals.

Some simplified code to demonstrate the point.

```
from timeit import Timer

d = {'turn on': 1, 'turn off': 0}

light = lambda c : d[c]

t = Timer(lambda: light('turn on'))
print('light: ' + str(t.timeit(number=23163958)))

# light: 3.66314601898
```

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense. But in `d` it is not possible to reference to the `v` I use in `toggle`. So dict might not be the best option here or can I use `v` somehow in your solution as well?

Comment: i couldn't immediately think of a way to include `v`, but there could well be a better approach.

Comment: @amuttsch The larger the dict is the huger the performance difference will be. A two-element dict is probably slower than a simple `if .. else` -- a thousand-element dict is going to be *way* faster than a thousand-element `if .. elif` dropthrough,

Comment: light = {'turn on': lambda x: 1,
                'turn off': lambda x: 0,
                'toggle': lambda x: (x+1)%2} works as well, even a bit faster than the ìf` statements. Thanks for the explanation, I got the issue with my previous code.