# BigO for dictionary method 'get(key)'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Does anybody know what O(?) for python's dictionary 'get(key)' method?

I've tested it with cProfile module and get same results of time for 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 100000000 records in the dictionary.

Does it means that python's dictionary provides O(1) access time for any key?

Comment: See http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Yes. Dictionaries are implemeted as hash key which have O(1) for lookup

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time complexity of accessing a Python dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963507/time-complexity-of-accessing-a-python-dict)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513882/python-list-vs-dict-for-look-up-table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is - YES, because Python dicts use Hashes to store keys. And a hash table has `O(1)` average time complexity to access its keys - read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table.

The worst case scenario for key retrieval is `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of keys in the `dictionary`. (@Michael Butscher).

Comment: Except for pathological cases with massive hash collisions. Worst case is O(n) where n is the number of keys

Comment: Worst case is very, very, very hard to reach though.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @MichaelButscher! Until you mentioned that, I was unaware that was even possible, because rainbow-tables are so successful one wouldn't suspect they would have a bottleneck.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, except if someone uses his own class(es) for keys and writes a bad hash function (but this is not very likely either).

Comment: @MichaelButscher So that's implementing the `__hash__()` method for your custom objects, right?

Comment: @MorganWilde yes, you would probably also need to implement `__eq__` too for proper checks (in case of hash collision)

Comment: That's not *amortized* time complexity. Amortized complexity would mean: For any sequence of n operations on the dictionary, the *total* time is as if each operation took O(1) time - an individual operation may still take more time though. One example is appending to an over-allocating array, where appending. As http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity notes, the correct term is *average*.

Comment: @delnan I didn't have "amortized" in the original and I do feel that average suits this better, but I may be out of my depth... :)

Comment: It doesn't suit better, it's simple correct whereas "amortized" is not. Hopefully the user who edited that in sees my explanation. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is really O(1) for any key.