# Is a dictionary membership check in python a linear operation?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is a dictionary membership check in python a linear operation as in O(n)?
For instance:

```
Dct = {"a":0,"b":1,"c":2,"d":3}
if d in Dct:
    #do something
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Time complexity of accessing a Python dict](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1963507) ?

Comment: **TL;DR**: nope, `O(1)` on average.

Answer (score 2):

No.

A dict is implemented as a hash table therefore the hash calculation takes time and the lookup is just O(1).

The dict also optimizes itself automatically regarding the memory size in order to prevent large buckets.

For more info regarding hash tables, you may see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).