# Would Speed or Style/Compactness of Code be Better in Classes?

Tags: performance, python-3.x, class, optimization

I realize that the answer will vary depending upon the situation and purpose of the code. I was writing a class in a module and realized that redefining the operator methods of the class took quite a lot of code. We use inheritance for classes themselves, why not methods? It does, of course, slow it down a little, but it makes the code much more succinct.

Take the following classes for example:

```
class Ex1:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
    def __add__(self, other):
        # Many lines of essential code
        return self.v + other.v
    def __sub__(self, other):
        # Many lines of essential code
        return self.v - other.v
    def __mul__(self, other):
        # Many lines of essential code
        return self.v * other.v
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        # Many lines of essential code
        return self.v / other.v
```

and:

```
import operator as ops

class Ex2:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
    def __op__(self, other, op):
        if op == '+':
            op = ops.add
        elif op == '-':
            op = ops.sub
        elif op == '*':
            op = ops.mul
        elif op == '/':
            op = ops.truediv
        # Many lines of essential code
        return op(self.v, other.v)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__op__(other, '+')
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.__op__(other, '-')
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.__op__(other, '*')
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self.__op__(other, '/')
```

Testing them with the timeit module I get this:

```
>>> timeit('Ex1(352) + Ex1(139)', 'from __main__ import Ex1')
1.2401711247332514
>>> timeit('Ex1(352) + Ex1(139)', 'from __main__ import Ex1')
1.2278626568422624
>>> timeit('Ex1(352) + Ex1(139)', 'from __main__ import Ex1')
1.2270929157546107
>>>
>>> timeit('Ex2(352) + Ex2(139)', 'from __main__ import Ex2')
1.6781722774976515
>>> timeit('Ex2(352) + Ex2(139)', 'from __main__ import Ex2')
1.6906975044787487
>>> timeit('Ex2(352) + Ex2(139)', 'from __main__ import Ex2')
1.678191572340893
```

So `Ex2` is about `1.36` times slower than `Ex1`. But in some (rare) situations if one were to use the "work around" of `Ex2`, one would be able to eliminate hundreds of lines of code. But in general, would speed be valued over eliminating lines? Would a professional prefer to sacrifice a little speed to eliminate redundant lines of code?

**Edit:**

I realized that I can eliminate the if-statements by replacing the `op` parameter (from the symbol; eg. '+') with the actual function (eg. ops.add).

Comment: I can't see how you eliminated lines there. If you have redundant lines, put those in a method, and call this method, than do the non-redundant stuff, but don't aggregate nicely seperated calls in one call just to seperate it again.

Comment: `# If-elif statements are faster than dictionaries`

Have you done any tests to show that? I truly doubt that statement.

Comment: Also, tests I've done myself show the opposite.

Comment: @DeepSpace You are right. I apologize. In my initial tests, I was creating the dictionary in __init__ instead of before __init__. It's the creation of the dictionary each time that is slower than the if statements.

Comment: @DeepSpace In fact, further testing has shown that somehow a dictionary look-up is faster than simply providing the functions themselves as the parameter. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @ClaytonGeist See this answer and the links it points to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1963514/1453822 Dictionary lookup time in Python is O(1) on (even more than) average.

Comment: @DeepSpace That's all fine, but I still don't understand how a lookup would be faster than actually inputting the value that would be returned by the lookup. How would `d={key:func...}; d[key](val)` be faster than `func(val)`?

Comment: @ClaytonGeist You can use `d[key](val)` instead.