# How can I transpose an array of values into a matching array of indices using numpy vectorization?

Tags: python, arrays, vectorization

I have a numpy array of sample pairs (2-D) and an array of samples (1-D). I want to convert the sample pairs to a matching array (i.e. 2-D) representing the indices of the sample array. Is there a faster solution than what I have already employed?

```
import numpy as np
pair_list = np.array([['samp1', 'samp4'],
                ['samp2', 'samp7'],
                ['samp2', 'samp4']])
samples = np.array(['samp0', 'samp1', 'samp2', 'samp3', 'samp4', 'samp5',
                 'samp6', 'samp7', 'samp8', 'samp9'])

vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda s: np.where(samples == s)[0])
pair_indices = vfunc(pair_list)

In [180]: print(pair_indices)
[[1 4]
 [2 7]
 [2 4]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use dictionaries because of its performant [time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963507/time-complexity-of-accessing-a-python-dict).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pair_list = np.array([['samp1', 'samp4'],
                ['samp2', 'samp7'],
                ['samp2', 'samp4']])
>>> samples = {'samp0':0, 'samp1':1, 'samp2':2, 'samp3':3, 'samp4':4, 'samp5':5,
                 'samp6':6, 'samp7':7, 'samp8':8, 'samp9':9}
>>> vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x: samples[x])
>>> pair_indices = vfunc(pair_list)
>>> print(pair_indices)
[[1 4]
 [2 7]
 [2 4]]
```

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
pair_list = np.array([['samp1', 'samp4'],
            ['samp2', 'samp7'],
            ['samp2', 'samp4']])
samples = np.array(['samp0', 'samp1', 'samp2', 'samp3', 'samp4', 'samp5',
             'samp6', 'samp7', 'samp8', 'samp9'])

def f1(pair_list,samples):
    vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda s: np.where(samples == s)[0])
    return vfunc(pair_list)

def f2(pair_list,samples):
    d = dict()
    for idx,el in enumerate(samples): d[el]=idx
    return np.array([d[el] for row in pair_list for el in row]).reshape(pair_list.shape[0],2)
```

`f2` looks clumsy, but...

```
timeit f1(pair_list,samples)
25.7 µs ± 78 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

timeit f2(pair_list,samples)
9.09 µs ± 68.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Try it on your machine and see how it goes for you! Of course, it'll be even better if you have the ability to reuse `samples`, since in that case you only have to convert `samples` to a `dict` once.

**Edit:** It's much, much better to vectorize `dict` access, as suggested by Mohsen_Fatemi, even if `samples` can't be reused.

```
def f3(pair_list,samples):
    d = dict()
    for idx,el in enumerate(samples): d[el]=idx
    vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x: d[x])
    return vfunc(pair_list)

timeit f3
16.1 ns ± 0.0138 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```