# Delete all keys in Python dictionary greater than x in constant time

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

If you have a dictionary:

```
d = {1: True, 2: False, 3: False, 4: True, 5: False, 6: True, 7: False, 8: False}
```

and you want all keys greater than 3 to be deleted so the dictionary becomes:

```
{1: True, 2: False, 3: False}
```

can you do this in constant time if the keys are sorted?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: No, it's going to scale by the number of keys.

Comment: Can you describe the scenario, and the reason behind this unusual request? That will determine if any workaround is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, we cannot do it in constant time.

To remove all the keys greater than 3 we can simply do:

```
{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k<=3} 
#{1: True, 2: False, 3: False}
```

We have a `for-loop` in above dictionary comprehension. Its time complexity is `O(n)`.

However, you can access individual elements in constant time, like:

```
d[3]
#False   constant Time complexity O(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you always want to go upto a fixed number, say k; doing this might be a good solution:

```
new_dict = {}
for i in range(1,k+1):
    new_dict[i] = old_dict[i]
```

Since the k is fixed, its constant time complexity

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1963514/19708285), accessing a dictionary is practically just constant time.